# Calculated Columns in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have two columns in a table (Access DB):

- Open_DATE
- Closed_Date

I would like to define a third column in a table which calculates the difference in days taking the difference between the above mantioned dates.
What is the best practice to do this in Access?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a *query*:

```
Select 
    Open_Date, 
    Closed_Date, 
    DateDiff("d", Open_Date, Closed_Date) As Days
From 
    YourTableName
```

Comment: Are you saying that calculated columns can be done ONLY at Query level? Is that the best practice? Use queries on top of tables. Then queries are used as basis for forms? First level - table. Second level - Query. Third level - Form. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is best practice to use queries and leave tables with core data only.

Comment: @Adam-technically, a query isn't the "only" way of doing what you wanted in your OP. In Access, you could create a calculated field within your table. But that's not a good idea, in most cases, because (a) it's not efficient with data that changes, like Gustav said, but also (b) having a calculated field in your table limits your ability to do some action queries later on.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL:

```
Select [{YourTableName}]![Open_Date]-[{YourTableName}]![Closed_Date] 
as {whatever you want to name the calculated field} from [{YourTableName}];
```

Comment: Posted at the same time as Gustav...you should get the same result either way

Comment: Are you saying that calculated columns can be done ONLY at Query level? Is that the best practice? Use queries on top of tables. Then queries are used as basis for forms? First level - table. Second level - Query. Third level - Form. Is this correct?